# How to specify a range without limiting to numbers

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler, range

This is the code that gets the restaurant reviews. I am collecting reviews.

The range is specified and imported. But there is a problem. Each store has a different number of reviews. Store with little reviews should go to next store soon.

I am suffering from too large a scope. But it can not reduce the scope. This is because some shops have reviews in this range.

How can I work effectively?

I saw find all?(element) searching this code. But I do not know if I've mistakenly applied my code.

```
#python3
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
from urllib.parse import quote
import time
import os
import xlwt
import random

import re

FISRT_URL = "https://www.yelp.com/search?
find_desc=Korean+Food&find_loc=Seattle,+WA&start="
LAST_URL = "&cflt=korean"
def get_link(URL, doc_name):
    global jisu_i
    global num
    global page
    for jisu_i in range(1):
        current_page_num = 20 + jisu_i*10
        position = URL.index('t=')
        URL_with_page_num = URL[: position+2] + str(current_page_num) \
                            + URL[position+2 :]
    print(URL_with_page_num) 
    importurl = URL_with_page_num
    r = requests.get(importurl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.decode('euc-kr','replace'), "lxml")
    time.sleep(random.randint(10, 15))

    for title in soup.find_all('h3')[page+2:21]:

        page = page + 1
        title_link = title.select('a')
        for jisu_m in range(130):
            print(page)
            last_URL = title_link[0]['href']
            print(last_URL)

            first_URL = "https://www.yelp.com"
            global article_URL
            article_URL = first_URL + last_URL
            time.sleep(random.randint(15, 30))



            jisuurl = article_URL
            for k in range(99):  #
                jisu_page_num = 0 + k * 20  #
                position = jisuurl.index('?')  
                URL_with_page_num = jisuurl[: position + 1] + str("start=") + str(jisu_page_num)

                jisu_with_page_num = URL_with_page_num
                print(jisu_with_page_num)

                jisu_importurl = jisu_with_page_num
                get_text(URL, jisu_importurl, doc_name)
                time.sleep(random.randint(40,180))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yelp has a very well documented API here: https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3

This is the only reliable way of interacting with the site programatically.